# Error occurred after migrating application from COldFusion 8 to ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, migration, coldfusion-10

XXX is a search engine application which searches for documents contained in various applications including App YYY. The issue is when App YYY document is searched in XXX and clicked to view the same, it is not opening.

Both the applications are in CF10 now and the issue is observed after migration of XXX from CF8 to CF10, earlier XXX was on CF8 and YYY was on CF10 and both applications were working fine.

This is my code snippet -

```
        <!--- check response from application 1 and react accordingly --->
        <cfif LEFT(TRIM(UCASE(CFHTTP.fileContent)), 4) is "TRUE">
                    <cfset request.MoleculeLibraryUser = TRUE>
                    <cfcookie name="cookie.MolLib_ID" expires="NOW">
        <cfelse>
                    <cfset request.MoleculeLibraryUser = FALSE>
                    <cfset flag = SetDisplayError("You did not come from a valid molecule library session.  Please go back to Molecule Library and log in again.")>
                    <cfset logonError = TRUE>
                    <cfif IsDefined("cookie.MolLib_ID")>
                                <cfcookie name="cookie.MolLib_ID" expires="NOW">
                    </cfif>
        </cfif>
```

Whenever the user clicks on the search link, it redirects to login page with the error message

"You did not come from a valid molecule library session.  Please go back to Molecule Library and log in again."

Comment: Your description doesn't give us much to go on. Please specify the exact issue so people can help you. [Please check](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [this](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Voting to close as the question, as asked, isn't really possible to sensibly comment on.

Comment: Could this be related to verity collections?

Comment: @Adam please go through the code snippet and question again...

Comment: You are getting the message because the logic you use (which, you do not need to `ucas()` the fileContent) is returning false. Post a `cfdump` of the `cfhttp` request.

Comment: Hi @Anjan. Scott's said what I would have.

Comment: Hi @ScottStroz thanks for the reply. It might be helpful for me, but can you please write the code snippet for what you said. It will be helpful for me as I didn't use cfdump for cfhttp request. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks @AdamCameron , please help me in coding the statement, it will be helpful for me... as I didn't use cfdump for cfhttp request.

Comment: Just read the docs and do your own work, @Anjan.

Comment: Sorry, I will not do the work for you. Try searching Google for `cfdump` to get you started on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Please check If you have imported all CF admin settings from CF8 to CF10 esp Allowed IP addresses for the application. If you can give clear error screen shot, it becomes easy to trace. Also check all the dependencies of the viewer are properly configured in CF10.

Comment: Thanks @Ramki. I have added the codesnippet in the question. Please check. Yeah I have imported all CF admin settings from CF8 to CF10